# Let $a\in S^d$, $b\in S^{d-1}$ be uniform on the spheres. How to show $\mathbb E[\frac{||a||_1}{\sqrt {d+1}}] \le\mathbb E[\frac{||b||_1}{\sqrt d}]$?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $a\in S^d$ and $b\in S^{d-1}$ be points chosen uniformly at random on the $(d+1)$ and $d$-dimensional spheres.

I'm interested in showing some inequalities regarding their norms, the simplest being:

> **How to show that $\mathbb E\left[\frac{||a||_1}{\sqrt {d+1}}\right] \le \mathbb E\left[\frac{||b||_1}{\sqrt d}\right]$?**

Next, I'm looking for:

> **How to show that $\mathbb E\left[\frac{||a||_1^2}{{d+1}}\right] \le \mathbb E\left[\frac{||b||_1^2}{ d}\right]$?**

---

We verified, using a monte carlo simulation, that these hold for all small-ish $d$ values, and that they hold as equalities when $d$ tends to $\infty$.

This question is somewhat related to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391195/is-mathbb-e-left-fracdx-12-right-o1-for-all-d-in-mathbb-r-w).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}$Your first inequality is true, for each $n:=d\ge2$.
Note that $a$ and $b$ equal, respectively, $X_{n+1}$ and $X_n$ in distribution, where
\begin{equation*}
    X_n:=G/|G|,
\end{equation*}
$G=(G_1,\dots,G_n)$ is a standard Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb R^n$, and $|G|$ is the Euclidean norm of $G$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    E\|X_n\|_1=n\,EY,
\end{equation*}
where $Y:=|G_1|/|G|$, so that $Y^2$ has the beta distribution with parameters $1/2,(n-1)/2$, and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{E\|X_n\|_1}{\sqrt n}=f_n:=\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt\pi}\,\frac{\Ga(n/2)}{\Ga((n+1)/2)}, 
\end{equation*}
and your first inequality means that
\begin{equation*}
    r_n:=f_n/f_{n+1}\overset{\text{(?)}}\ge1. \tag{$*$}
\end{equation*}

Note that
\begin{equation*}
    \rho_n:=\frac{r_{n+2}}{r_n}=\frac{(n+2)^{3/2}}{(n+1)^{3/2}}\,\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3}}<1
\end{equation*}
for $n>0$, because
\begin{equation}
    \rho_n^2-1=-\frac{2 n+3}{(n+1)^3 (n+3)}<0.
\end{equation}
So, $r_{n+2j}$ is decreasing in $j\in\{0,1,\dots\}$, for each $n>0$.
Also, it is easy to see that $r_n\to1$ (as $n\to\infty$). So, $r_n>1$ for all $n>0$, that is, ($*$) holds, as desired.

---

Concerning the second inequality, Pierre PC showed in a comment that $E\|X_n\|_1^2=1+(n-1)2/\pi$. Hence, the ratio
\begin{equation}
    \frac{E\|X_n\|_1^2}{n}=\frac2\pi+\frac{1-2/\pi}n
\end{equation}
is decreasing in $n$, which means the the second inequality holds as well.

---

Asking multiple questions in one post is not encouraged on MathOverflow, I think.

Comment: I think this approach shows that $\mathbb E[\|b\|_1^2]=\frac2\pi(d-1) + \sqrt{\frac2\pi}$. I am not familiar with Dirichlet distributions, maybe it is just another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: @PierrePC : To find $E\|X_n\|_1^2$, you will need to find the expectation of the product of the absolute values of two coordinates of $X_n$, and the joint distribution of the squares of such two coordinates is the Dirichlet distribution with parameters $1/2,1/2,(n-2)/2$. So, how did you do it without using the Dirichlet distribution?

Comment: I may be wrong, but this is the way I was thinking about it. Since $\|G\|_1^2=(|G_1|+\cdots+|G_n|)^2$, we can expand the square on the right, and we find $(*)=d\mathbb E[G_1^2]+d(d-1)\mathbb E[|G_1|]^2$ for its expectation. Now $\|G\|_1^2 = |G|^2\cdot\|X_n\|_1^2$, and since $|G|$ and $X_n$ are independent, $\mathbb E[\|X_n\|_1^2]$ is given by the quotient of $(*)$ by $\mathbb E[|G|^2]=d\mathbb E[G_1^2]$. Since $\mathbb E[G_1^2]=1$ (expectation of a $\chi^2(1)$) and $\mathbb E[|G_1|]=\sqrt{2/\pi}$ (expectation of a $\chi(1)$), this should the expression above.

Comment: @PierrePC : I see now -- a clever use of independence.

Comment: Thank you! :) I see you also corrected a mistake of mine, I agree with your formula although I think the first expression you give should be divided by $n$, which yields the result you give for $\mathbb E[\|X_n\|_1^2]/n$.

Comment: Using the same method, I have a slightly different result for $\mathbb E[Y]$, though. I get $\Gamma(d/2)/(\sqrt\pi\times\Gamma((d+1)/2))$. This differs from your result by a factor $\sqrt{d/(d-1)}$, or something similar. This gives $\rho_n^2 = (n(n+2)^3)/((n+3)(n+1)^3)$, and since $n(n+2)^3 - (n+3)(n+1)^3 = -2n-3$, it actually shows that $\rho_n<1$. This is coherent with the computations of the OP since, as you mentioned, $f_n$ converges to a constant (I think $\sqrt{2/\pi}$).

Comment: @PierrePC : Thank you for your further comments. Hopefully, now my mistakes are corrected. :-)

Comment: Thank you both for the answer! I followed your suggestion and separated the last question, which is now here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391461/let-g-n-g-1-g-2-ldots-g-n-be-a-vector-of-n-i-i-d-normal-variables-how-t.